# Java Mail: won't sent an email

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, email

I have a code that worked fine earlier on, but now it won't sent emails.
Is there something wrong in my code?

There is an error that says that the program couldn't connect with the SMTP server of Google.

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;

import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;


public class Mailing
{

    public Mailing()
    {


    }
    public void getMail(String warning,String subject)
    {
        final String username = "wim81.vangeyt@gmail.com";
        final String password = "Minidisc";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.startssl.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("wim81.vangeyt@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("wimvangeyt@outlook.com"));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(warning);

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Mailing mailing = new Mailing();
        mailing.getMail("test", "test mail");
    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried debugger?

Comment: Aha I found the problem, I did use the wrong port. Thanks anyway for your comment.

Comment: Then you might consider to delete this question.

Comment: No I still have another question regarding the class above. I use this class via another class who is calling the getMail() method. But maybe i better can ask that question in another thread?

Comment: @user3198205 Another question is another question. Put some effort into asking it, since you expect others to put effort into answering it. Voted to close.

Answer (score 0):

May be enable the settings in gmail account which you have given in the code from where the email can be sent. probably this would help you.